# Proof that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y}_i-y)^2$ is a biased estimator of the residual variance

Tags: statistics, expected-value, parameter-estimation

I know that $\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y}_i-y)^2$ is an unbiased estimator of the residual variance. Therefore I am obviously making a mistake when checking if $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y}_i-y)^2$ is unbiased, because I get that the answer is yes.

My assumptions on $\varepsilon_i$ are: linear, homoscedastic, gaussian with $\mu=0, \sigma=1$ and independent. This is my work:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\varepsilon_i)^2\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i^2)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{V}(\varepsilon_i)+[\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i)]^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma^2=\sigma^2$$
Where is my mistake?

Comment: $\hat y -y\neq\varepsilon$, recall $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ but $\hat y=X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top y=X\hat\beta$. I believe you are confounding $\beta$ and $\hat\beta$.

Comment: The residuals (which are not the errors) do not have variance exactly $\sigma^2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100557/proof-e-hat-sigma-2-e-left-frac1n-2-sigmay-i-haty-i2-right?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are confusing errors with residuals.**

Consider the simple linear regression model

$$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i+\varepsilon_i \quad,\,i=1,2,\ldots,n$$

where the errors $\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_n$ are independent $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

The $i$th residual is $\hat \varepsilon_i=y_i-\hat y_i=y_i-\hat\beta_0-\hat\beta_1 x_i$, where $(\hat\beta_0,\hat\beta_1)$ is the least square estimator of $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$. This of course is not same as $\varepsilon_i$.

The $i$th residual has mean $0$ but

$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat \varepsilon_i)=\sigma^2\left(1-\frac1n-\frac{(x_i-\overline x)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2}\right)$$

For details, see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/115011/119261) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3997405/321264).

It follows that

$$\operatorname E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \hat \varepsilon_i^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname E \left[\hat \varepsilon_i^2\right]
=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(\hat \varepsilon_i)=\sigma^2 \left(n-2\right)$$

For easier proofs of the last statement, see [Proof $E[\hat \sigma ^2] = E\left( \frac{1}{n-2} \Sigma(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2 \right) = \sigma ^2$: Linear Regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3100557/321264) and [Proof that $E[SS_E] = (n-2)\sigma^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3319241/321264).